# How can I make an another block of items under a grid in tkinter? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a 'maze' game with tkinter, and I wanted to display some things under the grid(game area), and this happend:

[image]

Because I wanted to put the text in the last line and the first column of the grid.

```py
frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.grid(row=line+1, column=0)
label = tk.Label(master=frame, text="Dashing:")
label.pack()
```

Any ideas, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the frame span all of the columns:

```
frame.grid(row=line+1, column=0, columnspan=17)
```